# move field up/down in a table using phpmyadmin?

Tags: phpmyadmin

is there a way to move an existing entry up/down in a table?

i cant see any button for it in phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 10):

You can move field up down easily with syntax like this.

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name` MODIFY `column_you_want_to_move` DATATYPE AFTER `column`
```

Comment: can we do it using graphical interface?

Answer (score -1):

If your table doesn't contain any data yet you can simply rename the columns in this case. However; It's not necessary, it really doesn't matter that much in which order the columns are.